# Why use a var when you can use a val with a mutable type?

Tags: scala, akka

I notice in many akka examples, in order to show how you can use mutable type inside of an Actor they use:

```
var users: Map[String, String] = ...
```

Why don't people use:

```
val users = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
```

You can still mutate the Map but just cant' change the reference.

Is there a significant difference between the 2 approaches?

Comment: Because a local `var` is more contained that a `mutable.Map`. For example, with the first one you can just return the value of the var and be sure you are not sharing mutability with the outside world, with the second you would need to do a defensive copy before the return. So even if a `mutable.Map` is more _efficient_ for additions, if you are sharing it constantly it would be more inefficient.

Comment: This is especially true if you see that `var` is public - then you should assume that someone else somewhere is accessing your data, and if they want to update it they'd better come through your gateway (here: generated setter that you might replace later with something more complex).

Comment: ok so in this case it is more of exposing properties to the outside world that should be kept private...

Comment: Because a mutable collection (not under concurrent) is not thread safe. Other threads may read and write the same object at the same time. An immutable collection variable is thread safe, because they could modify the reference instead of the object, although different threads may read different versions of the variable (which is generally acceptable in a distributed system). In a single threaded environment, both have the same behavior

Comment: @texasbruce Akka Actors are single-threaded, so thread safety is not an issue.

Comment: @Tim It is more of a general answer than just for Akka. Even for Akka, it could have threading issue, if you have child actors accessing parent's instance members.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case there are issues about visibility of this data, as discussed in the comments. But these don't apply in the case of an Actor because the only way to access data is through messages to the Actor. The actor state is not directly visible to code outside the Actor, so there are no concerns about sharing mutable data.

The main difference between using `var` and using `mutable` is that with `var` the whole collection is replaced but with `mutable` the collection is updated in place. Updating a collection in place is not functional, so the `mutable` version tends to encourage non-functional code whereas the `var` version encourages a more functional programming style.

But Actor state should really be held in the `Behavior` (for typed Actors) or managed via `context.become` in classic Actors. In both these cases the state consists of immutable values so, again, the `var` model is closer to this than using `mutable` collections.

Comment: In the Akka context, it should also be noted that a `val` of `mutable` opens up a possible way to subtly break the single-thread illusion which Akka provides: putting the mutable collection into a message without a defensive copy can mean that code outside the actor can directly manipulate state inside an actor (and this would even break `context.become` or typed `Behavior`).